# Encoding Agnostic File I/O Error

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to create functions that will read & write files regardless of their encoding (to an extent).

But I am getting an error when trying to write a file that is UTF-8.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5136: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whats going wrong and how can I fix it?

```
def file_read_agnostic(filePath):
    # Read file regardless of encoding (UTF-16-LE, UTF-8, ANSI)
    # Use BeautifulSoup to determine encoding

    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filePath, 'r').read())
    encoding = soup.originalEncoding

    try:
        return soup.contents[0].decode(encoding)
    except Exception, e:
        return soup.contents[0]

def file_write_agnostic(filePath, contents):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
    encoding = soup.originalEncoding

    f = open(filePath, mode='w')
    f.write(soup.contents[0])
    f.close()

# error occurs here
file_write_agnostic("a.txt", myUTF7Content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the file to bytes before writing (the error is happening because Python is attempting to coerce the data to bytes before writing and can't fit unicode characters into ASCII (which is the default encoding).

So need to change `f.write(soup.contents[0])` to `f.write(soup.contents[0].encode(encoding))`.  This will maintain the encoding in the written file as well.